# Setting disk quotas with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, disk-space, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I’m looking to apply disk quotas to an organizational unit in Active Directory, so that said quota applies to all users in it, but have no idea how to do it.
¿How can I do this?

P.S: I’m using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: You need to look at Group Policy. That's where settings are set and applied to AD objects and OUs. Based on your question I'm going to recommend that you do a significant amount of research into Group Policy and Active Directory BEFORE you make any changes. Changes made in here can cause issues if not made with careful consideration and planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All this is given with the strong recommendation that you study up on Active Directory and Group Policy. Also, you should learn Google because Microsoft has thoroughly documented Group Policy, and a simple Google search on this and nearly any other topic relevant to AD and GP should be your first stop whenever you have a question about these. Your question indicates that you lack necessary familiarity with these systems, and therefore the chance of unintended and serious consequences is quite high.**

Open Group Policy Management using an account with appropriate permissions.

Create a new Group Policy Object (GPO) and link it to the OU you wish to apply it to. As Disk Quotas apply to Computer objects (not user objects) you'll want to apply it to the OU containing computer objects (and probably not server objects).

Edit the GPO.

Navigate to **Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Disk Quotas**.

You will need to at least **Enable disk quotas** and **Specify default quota limit and warning level** and choose an action among the remaining options.

It's probably best to start with the logging options, and collect and review the logs to determine whether the policy is working and who will have problems with the quotas. After collecting the data for a period of time you can choose to enable enforcement of the quota.